# FileUpload Null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to use FileUpload Control to save Image to Database. The HasFiles return always false after I click on BtnSave.  I tried with and without UpdatePanel but could not find the solution.

My code is:

```
  protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
        {
            var ChNumber = txtNumber.Text;

            string img = this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
  //Save image to database function
        }
 else
 {
  lblStatus.Text="Image not Uploaded";
 }
 }
```

Comment: So where is the null reference error?

Comment: Keep in mind that the FileUpload control doesn't work when it is inside an UpdatePanel.

Comment: The reason that the file isn't been saved isn't in this code

Comment: if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true) always return false even I navigate to an image @yosi.

Comment: FileUplaod is already outside the UpdatePanel. It has null when I run my application in Debug mode. I am stuck in for the whole day but still unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a simple form without UpdatePanel. Here's the markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code:

```
using System;

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)
        {
            var ChNumber = txtNumber.Text;

            string img = this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            //Save image to database function
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Image not Uploaded";
        }
    }
}
```

I set a brekapoint at `if (FileUpload1.HasFile == true)` and see the uploaded file is there.

Comment: Thanks to you both gallery boy and afzalulh, the problem is with UpdatePanel. Now I am trying to use Ajax AsynFileUplad. But when I drag it on my Form. It show me missing reference error.